# How to use ffmpeg to encode video in H.264?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I have installed ffmpeg 3.0 from https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg, I am trying to convert a video coded with mepeg4 part 2 to H264, but I got `Unknown encoder 'libx264'`
 error

Here is my comannd: (I tried h264, x264, libx264, none of them worked)

```
ffmpeg -i Fashion.divx -acodec aac -vcodec libx264  out.mp4
```

I checked the list of supported codec

```
Codecs:
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
 ....L. = Lossy compression
 .....S = Lossless compression
 -------
 D.VI.. 012v                 Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
```

Here is h264:

```
 D.V.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_vdpau)
```

I am using ffmpeg 3.0, from that list, it seems that encoding with h264 is not supported, only decoding h264 is supported, right?

I tried to enable h.264 with this guide 
[How to quickly compile FFmpeg with libx264 (x264, H.264)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20quickly%20compile%20FFmpeg%20with%20libx264%20%28x264,%20H.264%29)

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
```

bu I get 
 ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264

```
ERROR: libx264 not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

what should I do to make encode video in h.264 work?

Comment: Step 1 from the quick compilation guide you linked: **Compile x264**

Comment: yes, I just found out I need to install libx264 separately, thx.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I just found out I need to install libx264 separately, here is the command

```
sudo apt-get install yasm libvpx. libx264.
```

Indeed after install libx264, I get

```
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )
```

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, you've already answered your own question:

> Here is h264:
>
> ```
>  D.V.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_vdpau)
> ```

As the listing suggests, the encoder's name is `h264`, the codec's name can be found **between the braces**.

So your command should look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i Fashion.divx -acodec libfaac -vcodec h264  out.mp4
```

My FFmpeg version has libx264, so the `-codecs` option prints me this:

```
DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )
```

As you can see, I could use `-vcodec libx264` or `-vcodec libx264rgb`.